# Trying to use objects from an entirely different model using a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I want to assign a 'Rank' to specific users with a Foreign key (I created a model for Ranks with other objects such as an image, description, etc).

What I want to do is to use those objects from the Rank Model and bring them over to my template. So that when I assign the rank "Newbie" to a specific user, it will show all the objects from the Rank like image, and descriptions.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Here's my views.py

```
from .models import user as UserModel

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')

def user(request, user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserModel, pk=user_id)
    context = {
        'profile' : profile,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/user.html', context)
```

Here is the model for Ranks

```
from django.db import models


class Ranks(models.Model):
    rank_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/&Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    rank_points = models.IntegerField()
    rank_promotionss = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank_name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple - add [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) field to your user model:

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
...
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Ranks, on_delete=models.CASCADE,...)
```

and then use it in your template simply by calling e.g. `profile.rank.rank_name`

1 little optimization tip, in your `user()` method, add `select_related` column:

```
def user(request, user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserModel.objects.select_related('rank'), pk=user_id)
```

or it would perform additional queries to fetch the Rank

Another tip, keep your models names in singular, e.g. `Rank` instead of `Ranks`